Is there any way to fetch data quickly from InfluxDB V2 using a Flux script?
Influx DB
I am trying to fetch data from InfluxDB using a Flux V2 script, but it takes more than one second to return the data. I need to speed up the process. I am new to InfluxDB.
Flux script:
from(bucket:"myBucket")
|> range(start: 2024-05-01T00:00:00-07:00, stop: 2024-05-23T23:51:19-07:00)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "data" and r._field == "Value" and
(r.DeviceMetricId ==      "00001"))
|> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: mean, createEmpty: false, timeSrc: "_start")
|> group(columns: ["_time"])
|> mean()
|> keep(columns: ["_time", "_value"])
Query execution method
async queryData(fluxQuery: string): Promise<any> {
try {

  const result = await this.queryApi.collectRows(fluxQuery);
  return result;
} catch (error) {
  throw Error(error);
}`your text`

}
Notes: I have accessed the production InfluxDB from my local API. It takes more than 1 second to execute the query. I am using Node.js for the API
